# nested ternary operator vs nested if else, which is better in readability purpose

Tags: language-agnostic, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I found code in code review which was written by my team member. It contains nested ternary operator. I told him to use if else if there is more than one nesting for readability purpose. We had argue on that.

following is code

```
ColorEnum color = opacity == Opacity.FIVE? ColorEnum.BLACK : 
                opacity == Opacity.TEN? ColorEnum.WHITE :
                    opacity == Opacity.FIFTY? ColorEnum.RED :
                        opacity == Opacity.TWENTY? ColorEnum.BLUE :
                            opacity == Opacity.FIFTEEN? ColorEnum.PURPLE : null;
```

And this code is changing as new configurations come.

So What is better here? ternary operator or if else?

Comment: Questions that are just asking us for an opinion are not suited for StackOverflow as this is not a discussion forum. Please rephrase your question; the section on "Subjective Questions" on the [Help Page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just reformatting your code makes it quite clear:

```
ColorEnum color = 
          opacity == Opacity.FIVE    ? ColorEnum.BLACK
       :  opacity == Opacity.TEN     ? ColorEnum.WHITE 
       :  opacity == Opacity.FIFTY   ? ColorEnum.RED 
       :  opacity == Opacity.TWENTY  ? ColorEnum.BLUE 
       :  opacity == Opacity.FIFTEEN ? ColorEnum.PURPLE 
       :  null;
```

LISP adopts the `cond` construct which has both the same structure and the same semantics, and is considered good practice. As an aside, Clojure also supports a form which tests the value of a single expression with a single predicate applied to different values (one for each clause) and calls it `condp`—that would be a perfect match for your use case.

The idiom with the ternary operator has the advantage over an `if-else` cascade for being an *expression* so you need only a single statement to assign it to the variable. `if-else` will force you to pull the assignment into each `then` clause, introducing more boilerplate and more opportunity to fail on correctness.

A `switch` statement could also be considered as an alternative, but it would have the following deficiencies:

- like `if-else`, it is not an expression;
- you are restricted to just different *constant* values of a single expression (the type of the expression being quite constrained, too).
- it's prone to bugs due to the boilerplate `break` missing somewhere.

Comment: First time I've heard a reference to LISP when writing Java code. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas The original Java 1.0 architecture team contained several famed LISPers :)

Comment: so I cant use switch if there is expression instead of constant (enum)

Comment: @nilesh `switch` is primarily about performance and is compiled into a table lookup. This is why you can only use constants of predetermined types as switch labels.

Comment: then what if i have expressions in ternary operator? isn't if else will be more readable?

Comment: if-else is also a statement, so you are forced to repeat the assignment in every then-clause. Boilerplate usually decreases readability, but that's up to you.

Comment: What if the original poster is using automatic code formatting and "just reformatting the code" is not an option?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use `switch` statement. It would be more readable than ternary and `if-else`.

```
switch(opticity)
{
    case Opticity.FIVE: color = ColorEnum.BLACK;
    break;

    case Opticity.TEN: color = ColorEnum.WHITE;
    break;

    case Opticity.FIFTY: color = ColorEnum.RED;
    break;  

    ....

   default: printf("Error message\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, probably a switch-case statement would be best in terms of readability.

Answer (score 1):

Go with switch.

I've a thumb rule which I consistently follow (Although not hardset)

1) Only one conditional evaluation, go with ternary operator

2) Two conditional check, go with `if(){} else if(){ } else{}` construct

3) Three or more go with `switch` ladder

**“Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.”
― Harold Abelson, Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs**

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, a switch would be a good alternative. To reduce boilerplate code (breaks, assignments), I would further recommend putting the switch into a dedicated method:

(All examples are in C#)

```cs
public ColorEnum OpacityToColor(Opacity opacity)
{
  switch (opacity)
  {
    case Opacity.FIVE:
      return ColorEnum.BLACK;
    case Opacity.TEN:
      return ColorEnum.WHITE;
    case Opacity.FIFTY:
      return ColorEnum.RED;
    case Opacity.TWENTY:
      return ColorEnum.BLUE;
    case Opacity.FIFTEEN:
      return ColorEnum.PURPLE;
    default:
      throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("opacity");
  }
}

// Elsewhere
ColorEnum color = OpacityToColor(opacity);
```

If your language has a neat dictionary/map initialization syntax (e.g. Python, C#), you could also use that for a very concise and clear notation:

```cs
public static readonly Dictionary<Opacity, ColorEnum> ColorByOpacity = 
  new Dictionary<Opacity, ColorEnum>
{
  {Opacity.FIVE, ColorEnum.BLACK},
  {Opacity.TEN, ColorEnum.WHITE},
  {Opacity.FIFTY, ColorEnum.RED},
  {Opacity.TWENTY, ColorEnum.BLUE},
  {Opacity.FIFTEEN, ColorEnum.PURPLE}
};

// Elsewhere
ColorEnum color = ColorByOpacity[opacity];
```